# Understanding matrix operation.

Tags: matrices

- [13.2.1 Problem Statement](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Physics_and_Pedagogy/Computational_Physics_(Chong)/13%3A_The_Markov_Chain_Monte_Carlo_Method/13.02%3A_The_Ising_Model)

> [image]

Can you explain how the values of $E$ in Eq. 13.2.3 and 13.2.4 were derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that for a matrix:

$$S=\begin{pmatrix}S_{11}&S_{12}&S_{13}&S_{14}\\S_{21}&S_{22}&S_{23}&S_{24}\\S_{31}&S_{32}&S_{33}&S_{34}\\S_{41}&S_{42}&S_{43}&S_{44}\end{pmatrix}$$

they take as "$i$" and "$j$" the *pairs* of indices that are *adjacent* (e.g. $i=22, j=23$ or $i=22, j=12$), where adjacent also means "adjacent if you roll over the edge of the matrix and end on the other side" (e.g. $i=24, j=21$ or $i=12, j=42$) and then sum the products $S_iS_j$ over all those pairs, *without duplication*. It ends up being a long sum (for $4\times 4$ matrices: $32$ terms):

$$\begin{array}{cl}S_{11}S_{12}+S_{12}S_{13}+S_{13}S_{14}+S_{14}S_{11}&+\\S_{21}S_{22}+S_{22}S_{23}+S_{23}S_{24}+S_{24}S_{21}&+\\S_{31}S_{32}+S_{32}S_{33}+S_{33}S_{34}+S_{34}S_{31}&+\\S_{41}S_{42}+S_{42}S_{43}+S_{43}S_{44}+S_{44}S_{41}&+\\S_{11}S_{21}+S_{21}S_{31}+S_{31}S_{41}+S_{41}S_{11}&+\\S_{12}S_{22}+S_{22}S_{32}+S_{32}S_{42}+S_{42}S_{12}&+\\S_{13}S_{23}+S_{23}S_{33}+S_{33}S_{43}+S_{43}S_{13}&+\\S_{14}S_{24}+S_{24}S_{34}+S_{34}S_{44}+S_{44}S_{14}&\end{array}$$

In the first case all entries are $+1$ so all products are $1$ and the sum is $32$. In the second case, only one entry is $-1$, so $28$ products are $1$ and four are $-1$, giving the total sum of $24$.